# Why embedded component not get rerendered in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have two components: `Event` > `FormField`.

`Event` has a useState called `setEvent`.

```js
function Event(props: EventProps) {
  const [event, setEvent] = useState<EventOut | undefined>();
```

It is passed to `FormField`. `FormField` calls it when saving happens.

```js
props.setEvent(event);
```

`Event` has a useEffect on it, and it gets triggered:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    setEvent(event);
  }, [event]);
```

But following this, `FormField` will not get again rendered. What do I miss?

Do you think the is a "memo" problem? React perform only a shallow compare on `event`? `event` is a struct, not a primitive value. I do not use memo anyway.

Comment: You probably want to show this as [mcve] rather than several detached bits of code, because without the full picture, it's nearly impossible to tell what you missed.

Comment: If you're only passing `setEvent` down, there's no need for React to rerender as it won't change.

Comment: By the way, adding `event` to the dependency array of the `useEffect` hook, which actually updates that same piece of state, is definitely **wrong**, it's unclear what you're doing.

Comment: @goto1 you mean if I remove `[event]` `useEffect` the rendering cycle will be triggered also? It is enough call setter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setter function returned from `useState` is stable (its identity does not change from one render to the next). This means that when `Event` renders, the props to `FormField` are the same and React is able to opt-out of rendering to improve performance.

Comment: yes, but the setted `event` in `FormField` is different from the one `FormField` received, it was modified during save. Do you know, how can I force not do a shallow comparasion but check fields inside of `event`?

Comment: Your question doesn't specify that `event` is being passed to `FormField`. Between the infinite loop and the lack of clarity, I'm going to opt not to continue to try to guess at solutions. Further, it sounds like you are misunderstanding the effect of shallow comparison. If you'd like further help, share a minimal example of the code you would like help with.